# Parcel file descriptor null pointer exception using with mediaRecoredr.setFileOutput()

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-mediarecorder, parcelfiledescriptor

I am trying to record video from my android application to my desktop PC(Laptop).
I do this with Socket programming, In my android code Parcel File Descriptor throws null pointer exception and App is crashed.
Anybody help me.

```
private void SetupMediaRecorder ()throws IOException{
        task t = new task();
        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: MediaRecorder...");
        pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(t.m_socket);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: SET PATH...");
        mMediaRecoder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecoder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecoder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecoder.setOutputFile(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        mMediaRecoder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(40);
        mMediaRecoder.setVideoFrameRate(4);
   mMediaRecoder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(),mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecoder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecoder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mMediaRecoder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecoder.prepare();
    }

   public class task extends AsyncTask {
       Socket  m_socket = null;
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
            try {
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");
                m_socket = new Socket ("192.168.1.5",31001);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "PFD...");

                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: OUT ASYNC...");
                pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(m_socket);
                Log.e("TCP Client", "C: PFD initialize...");


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here is exception Details.

```
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp E/TCP Client: C: MediaRecorder...
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileDescriptor java.net.Socket.getFileDescriptor$()' on a null object reference
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:354)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.SetupMediaRecorder(Storage.java:542)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.StartRecording(Storage.java:366)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.CheckStoragePermission(Storage.java:511)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.access$1100(Storage.java:84)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage$3.onClick(Storage.java:240)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
10-26 00:09:19.921 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Due to above Exception MediaRecorder Goes to invalid State.

```
10-26 00:09:19.931 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp E/MediaRecorder: start called in an invalid state: 1
10-26 00:09:19.931 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-26 00:09:19.931 15696-15696/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp, PID: 15696
                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                                                        at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:938)
                                                                                        at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.CheckStoragePermission(Storage.java:512)
                                                                                        at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage.access$1100(Storage.java:84)
                                                                                        at com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp.Storage$3.onClick(Storage.java:240)
                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5716)
                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
10-26 00:11:53.821 15696-15702/com.example.habibrehman.cameraappp W/art: Suspending all threads took: 9.171ms
```

Comment: Where are the exception details?

Comment: I edit my question and Add Exception details.

Comment: Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: m_socket = new Socket ("192.168.1.5",31001); 
If its not connected its going to give you a null object. I'd check here first.

Comment: i check it connection is made up but still parcel file descriptor is null

Comment: Marxk Rotteveel thank you i check the link but i declare parcel file descriptor properly

Comment: can please any body help me how can i solve this